# How can I create an Apple ID for China if I live in the U.S.A

Tags: apple-id

I don't have a credit card I'm completely broke and I'm not jail token I'm just trying to get a free Chinese app from America ( Plants Vs. Zombies 2 Chinese Version).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make another apple account, there are tons if tutorials for that. When you get to verify or review or something on your iPhone you need to choose the country. You may not find "China" but at the end of the list is China written in Chinese (translate China via google and it works).

When you get to the address you must write like I did:

[image]

Comment: This one works for me!

Answer (score 1):

To download apps available for certain region, you will need an Apple ID assigned to this region. Most likely, you won't be able to change your region from the United States to China as you don't have a valid Chinese address and credit card issued in China. YOUR only option is to create a new Apple ID. Once you create an Apple ID, you will be prompted to select your country, this is where you should choose China, not the USA.

Below you will find the instructions:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203993

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to have a valid Chinese address and a Chinese credit card.

Comment: It's helpful if you provide links to where you get this info for confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.

When you go to change your country and it asks for a credit card, just click bank card instead and it lets you continue with no card numbers.